# Why isn't there a pager and it doesn't show two records per page?

Tags: 7

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'article', '=')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault') 
  ->limit(2);
$result = $query->execute();

while($record = $result->fetchObject()) {
  echo $record ->title."<br/>";
}

$output .= theme('pager', array('tags' => array()));
```

I put the above code in a page template file. Why isn't there a pager and it doesn't show two records per page?

Comment: Is [123](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/11921/123) a colleague of yours? You both keep asking questions about the same topic. `:)`

Comment: yes.:) we are in the same company, our company using drupal make site

Comment: @kiamlaluno,could you tell me why the above code not have pager and the result is not 2. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is wrong: Once you extend the query object, you need to save it, or it will get lost. The correct code is the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query = $query->condition('n.type', 'article', '=')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault') 
  ->limit(2);

$result = $query->execute();

foreach ($result as $node) {
  echo $node->title . "<br/>";
}
```

In my case, the result is the following one.

> Appellatio Fere Huic Metuo
> Ludus Vereor

See the note shown on [Extenders](http://drupal.org/node/508796):

> Note that `$query` is not altered in place. The new object is returned from `extend()`, and if it is not saved to a variable it will be lost.